# how to make all letters in the string capital?

Tags: ruby

I have a string from MD5 that looks like this:

```
@encrypted_str = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("1a2b3c").capitalize
=>Bf4ab447496f2d3d5a6c77c2cd12f996
```

but this .capitalize is making capital only first letter **B**

advice me please how to capitalize all letters in this MD5 result

Comment: This is 100% an RTFD question. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-upcase

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL - That is where I got it and I don't even know ruby.

Comment: @Xaisoft I know. Neither do I.

Comment: Also, this is not a Rails question, but Ruby.

Comment: RTFD takes several keys more to accomplish than LMGTFY and loads slower than SO on non-performant internet connections.  Enough so, that the "FD" may still be loading by the time you're unblocked, or it may never load at all. Go impose _your_ preferred workflow on somebody else and leave the questioner alone. People have obviously found it useful (hence the upvotes). Geez I'm sick of the hostile SO users that think they're way is the only way. This is why so many people are afraid to post anything here. OMG somebody is wrong on the internet! I must fix this with an off-topic comment </rant>

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try upcase:

```
@encrypted_str = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("1a2b3c").upcase
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 ways to do it: **upcase** and **upcase!**

1. **upcase** will capitalize all letters and return the string -> http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-upcase
2. **upcase!** will do the same saving the original object -> http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-upcase-21

Answer (score 2):

what you are looking for is upcase.

```
@encrypted_str = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("1a2b3c").upcase
=> "BF4AB447496F2D3D5A6C77C2CD12F996"
```

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html for more information on String manipulation

Answer (score 1):

TRY

```
@encrypted_str = Digest::MD5.hexdigest("1a2b3c").upcase
```